# OSM basemap WMS for 2 different years

Tags: openstreetmap, wms, basemap

Is it possible to get OSM basemap WMS for two different years ( 2000 and 2010 )

Comment: OpenStreetMap was founded in 2004, so your not going to be able to get data from 2000.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/39447/osm-wms-baselayers-for-two-different-years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [full planet dump](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Full_dump) and corresponding tools to create a dataset that contains the historic content of OSM and "undos" edits. This can be rendered with the ordinary mapnik rendering stack and published via WMS. There are also some animations out there that shows OSM growth during time (e.g. ITO, geofabrik ...).

But as @Jesse mentioned, OSM started in 2004: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/History_of_OpenStreetMap

Comment: Keep in mind that rendering such old data will be difficult. The database format has changed, including OSM's basic data elements, tools have changed, and so on.